# Examples using updated gdata-java-client with Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gdata-api, google-sheets

According to http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/detail?r=505 the gdata-java-client library has recently (April 2012) been updated with OAuth2.0 support. I'd love to use that in a web application, to create and modify google spreadsheets. I want users of my web app to have their data stored in a google spreadsheet under their own credentials.

I'm new to using google apis, and am getting quite lost while trying to wade through examples. They all seem to refer to deprecated auth methods (oauth1 or authsub or clientlogin).

Has anyone seen any good, recent samples on how to use gdata apis with Oauth2.0 to accomplish the sort of thing I'm talking about? Thanks very much in advance. And sorry if the question is too n00by.